# forecast from auto.arima doesn't line up with historical data

Tags: r, time-series

I'm modeling daily wastewater flow at a tourist location with yearly and weekly seasonality. I've done this by modeling the two seasonal patterns with fourier terms, including precipitation, number of wastewater connections, and holidays as regression terms, and inputting all of this information into auto.arima using xreg. The fit is incredibly good. The correlation between the fitted values and the observed values is 0.986. The problem I'm having is that the forecasted values don't line up with the historical values. The pattern is correct, but they are shifted downwards. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The graphs, the code, and data samples are included. Thanks in advance! Sorry if I'm doing stack wrong!

[Graph of Fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZimU.png)

[Graph of Forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FrmR.png)

```
MainData <- read.delim("MainData.txt")
PrecipR <- read.delim("PrecipR.txt")
library("dplyr")
library("forecast")
library("tidyr")
library('ggplot2')

#turn rain data into a daily rate (sum of rain divided by number of hours with rain)
duplicats<-duplicated(PrecipR[,1:4])
index<-which(duplicats==FALSE)
PrecipR<-PrecipR[index,]
dsum<-aggregate(Precip~Year + Month+ Day, sum, data=PrecipR)
dcount<-aggregate(Precip~Year + Month+ Day, FUN=function(Precip){sum(Precip>0)}, data=PrecipR)
prate<-dsum$Precip/dcount$Precip
precip<-cbind(dsum, dcount[,4])
colnames(precip)[5]<-"hcount"

#combine data
dat<-MainData[order(MainData$Year, MainData$Month, MainData$Day),]
dat<-merge(dat, precip, all.x=TRUE)
dat<-dat[order(dat$Year, dat$Month, dat$Day),]

#move to beginning of cycle and attach data
dat2006<-dat[which(dat$Year==2006),]
start<-which(dat$Influent.Flow==min(dat2006$Influent.Flow))
dat<-dat[-seq(1:start),]
attach(dat)

#add holiday dummy
holiday<-rep(0, nrow(dat))
holiday[which(dat$Month == 7 & dat$Day==4)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==18 & dat$Year==2016)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==20 & dat$Year==2015)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==21 & dat$Year==2014)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==22 & dat$Year==2013)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==16 & dat$Year==2012)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==18 & dat$Year==2011)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==19 & dat$Year==2010)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==20 & dat$Year==2009)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==21 & dat$Year==2008)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==16 & dat$Year==2007)]<-1
holiday[which(dat$Month == 8 & dat$Day==17 & dat$Year==2006)]<-1
index<-which(holiday==1)
holiday[index+1]<-1
holiday[index-1]<-1

#model auto.arima with weekly and yearly seasons using msts and Fourier terms
flow.msts<-msts(Influent.Flow, seasonal.periods=c(7, 365.25))
y <- msts(Influent.Flow, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
z <- fourier(y, K=c(2,2))

covariates.msts = cbind(Precip,
                        Connections,
                        holiday)
#main model
fit <- auto.arima(y, xreg=cbind(z,covariates.msts), seasonal=FALSE)
cor(Influent.Flow, as.numeric(fit$fitted),  use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

x<-seq(1:length(Influent.Flow))
plot(x, Influent.Flow, ylim=c(0,800000), main="Daily Waste Water Flow, Observed and Modeled Values", ylab="Flow (MGD)", xlab="Daily Values, 2006 to February 2017")
lines(x, fit$fitted, col="red")

#forcast between 2/17/17 and 5/23/17
p<-precip$Precip[which(precip$Year==2017,precip$Month>=2)]
covariates.forecast = cbind(Precip<-p[seq(1:95)],
                            Connections<-rep(max(Connections),95),
                            holiday<-rep(0,95))
colnames(covariates.forecast)<-colnames(covariates.msts)
zf <- fourier(y, K=c(2,2), h=95)

fc <- forecast(fit, xreg=cbind(zf,covariates.forecast), h=95)
```

---

```
> head(MainData)
    Date Month Day Year Influent.Flow Connections
1 1/1/06     1   1 2006        141166      484672
2 1/2/06     1   2 2006         99883      484672
3 1/3/06     1   3 2006        108132      484672
4 1/4/06     1   4 2006         88356      484672
5 1/5/06     1   5 2006         89273      484672
6 1/6/06     1   6 2006         71614      484672
> head(PrecipR)
  Year Month Day Hour Precip
1 2006     1   1    0   0.03
3 2006     1   1    1   0.02
4 2006     1   1    2   0.01
5 2006     1   1    3   0.00
6 2006     1   1    4   0.00
8 2006     1   1    5   0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. The model was over fit. I reduced the number of Fourier terms from 2 to 1. This only reduced the correlation between the fitted and the observed values from 0.986 to 0.983. And now the forecast makes sense. Link to new results below.

[New Forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIsBH.png)